# std::vector with size and value constructor fails to compile under MSVC 16.9

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdvector

Here is a minimal reproducible example of a problem I am having with std::vector and MSVC

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;    // For brevity

struct Struct
{
    vector< int > Values(6, 0);         // Should hold 6 zeros
    vector< int > NormalConstructor;    // Example of normal vector

    void Dump() { for (auto val : Values) { cout << val << " "; } }
};

int main()
{
    Struct s;

    s.Dump();

    cout << "\n";
}
```

The line `vector< int > Values(6, 0);`  results in `error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'`, and the variable named `Value` is being coloured as though it is a function declaration.

[image: Screenshot]

cppreference.com says this constructor **"3) Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value"**

There are several questions on here along these lines that I have looked at, but none seem to indicate what is wrong, or what I should do to avoid this error.

What should I be doing instead ?

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses initializer can't be used to initialize data member in default member initializer (since C++11). (The compiler is trying to interprete it as function declaration.)

You can use euqal-sign initializer instead.

```
struct Struct
{
    vector< int > Values = vector< int >(6, 0);  // Should hold 6 zeros
    vector< int > NormalConstructor;             // Example of normal vector

    void Dump() { for (auto val : Values) { cout << val << " "; } }
};
```

Or use member initializer list in constructor.

```
struct Struct
{
    vector< int > Values;
    vector< int > NormalConstructor;             

    void Dump() { for (auto val : Values) { cout << val << " "; } }

    Struct() : Values(6, 0) {}
};
```

Comment: Not according to cppreference.com. Here is an example from their vector constructor page
.
    // words4 is {"Mo", "Mo", "Mo", "Mo", "Mo"}
    std::vector<std::string> words4(5, "Mo");
.
.
and when I click on their "Run this code" button, that's exactly what I get...

Comment: Sorry, meant to add that I'm not trying to initialise a data member, I'm attempting to call it's constructor.

Comment: @GeoffreyArmstrong The syntax just can't be used for data member of struct/class, as I explained in the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see, can't do that in a class... I'll check that out. Thanks.

Comment: that is 100% right. Adding that assignment from your example works. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.